Gradient of an expectation of a function with respect to the expectation distribution
I'm trying to derive Eq. (6) in this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.13521), where r is defined as:
$$ r = \nabla_{d^1_\pi}0.5||\psi^1 - \psi^2||^2_2 $$, where $$\psi^i = \mathbb{E}_{s',a'\sim d^i_{\pi}(s,a)}\phi(s,a)$$
From product rule I expect the $r=(\psi^1 - \psi^2)\nabla_{d^1_\pi}(\psi^1) $, but I'm not sure what the gradient of the psi should be. In the paper it's claimed that $$r=\phi(s,a) \cdot (\psi^1 - \psi^2)$$
Why is the gradient of psi equal to phi in this case?
